# How to change and add new column with new ID names

Tags: r, excel, multiple-columns

I need to change column in many files. I have files in which my names in ID column are written wrong. I prepared excel files with 2 columns "wrong ID" and "new ID" and now I want to change it in every files.

for ex.

```
wrong ID         new ID
CALU1            calu-1
```

I have almost 300 different ID.

Answer (score 1):

We can keep the files in a `list` after reading them and then use `rename_at`

```
 library(dplyr)
 lst1 <- lapply(files, function(x) {

            x1 <- read.csv(x)
            x1 %>% 
                 rename_at(vars(df$`wrong ID`), ~ df$`new ID`)
            })
```